# How to dynamically call a module in React Native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I would like to have a react native View dynamically added. This will be completely undetermined before calling.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';

export default class HelloWorld extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>{ /** add a component a view depending on paremeters passed into class in Props**/}</View>
        );
    }
}
```

Since this will be completely undetermined I am not sure how to call a module from another module without first importing it.

How can I go about it?

Thank you all in advance.

How to dynamically call a module in React Native

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';

export default class HelloWorld extends Component {
    render() {
      let dynamicComponent = this.props.displayDynamicComponent ?  <DynamicComponent /> : null;
        return (
            <View>{dynamicComponent}</View>
        );
    }
}
```